# How to solve compile errors in custom JpaRepositoryFactory after upgrade from Spring Data JPA 1.4 to 1.8?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Basically this is the situation when I want to upgrade to 1.8.0.RELEASE from 1.4.5.RELEASE. What I've noticed so far is this:

- `LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor` has become `CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor`
- `LockMetadataProvider` has become `CrudMethodMetadata`

Now, we have some custom jpa repository factories and for that we extend `JpaRepositoryFactory` like this:

```
class CustomJpaRepositoryFactory extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

  protected <T, ID extends Serializable> JpaRepository<?, ?> getTargetRepository{

    SimpleJpaRepository<?, ?> repo; 
    // some custom code

    LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor lockModePostProcessor = LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.INSTANCE;
    repo.setLockMetadataProvider(lockModePostProcessor.getLockMetadataProvider());

  }
}
```

This was possible because the `LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor` enum was public. Now, the new `CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor` is package protected and the same trick will not work. I realized I can do this:

```
 super.getTargetRepository(metadata);
```

and in the back-end this will happen:

```
repository.setRepositoryMethodMetadata(lockModePostProcessor.getLockMetadataProvider());
```

But it seems way too misleading. Anyone from the Spring Data JPA project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefer overriding `JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata, EntityManager)`. This method is called from `JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata)` which will take care of populating the repository instance you created with the necessary `CrudMethodMetadata`.